# How to tell if someone has downloaded the latest code

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Is there a way I can tell (other than in the SVN Log...because it only shows me if someone committed) who has updated recently so that I know they have downloaded my code?  I'm looking specifically into updates (not commits which can obviously be seen in SVN Log).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - run your own subversion server, turn on logging, and read the logs.

**Edit**:  TortoiseSVN is a **client**.  Subversion is a **server**.  Imagine Tortoise being a browser (firefox) and Subversion being the webserver (apache or IIS).  What you want to do is read the *server logs* from Subversion (not the SVN Log, which is something completely different).

I don't know who or how you run your svn server.  I run svnserve on linux through apache (so I say https:// instead of svn://), and I can read subversion logs through apache.  They look like this:

```
[18/Oct/2009:14:21:41 -0400] xx.xx.xx.xx TLSv1 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA "OPTIONS /svn/terracidal/root HTTP/1.1" 401
[18/Oct/2009:14:21:42 -0400] xx.xx.xx.xx TLSv1 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA "OPTIONS /svn/terracidal/root HTTP/1.1" 401
[18/Oct/2009:14:21:45 -0400] xx.xx.xx.xx TLSv1 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA "OPTIONS /svn/terracidal/root HTTP/1.1" 194
[18/Oct/2009:14:21:45 -0400] xx.xx.xx.xx TLSv1 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA "PROPFIND /svn/terracidal/root HTTP/1.1" 696
```

Again, these are server logs, not the SVN Log.  I can crack up logging verbosity and see connections, debug statements, things about the running of the server - but also things like who's connecting and performing operations.  That's what you care about.  So if you or your company runs their own svn server, ask the admin if they can make the logs available for reading.  If you use a 3rd party, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: eh?  we have tortoise running on a server.  I'm asking what logs or how can I see who has updated..some sort of log.  I'm not asking about commits.  A commit updates the revision.  I want to know who's done an svn update only which I don't see in the Tortoise log.

Comment: unless someone commits, I won't see anything in the log.  If someone simply performs an SVN Update and hasn't committed in a while, there's got to be a way for me to see that somehwere..who, when, etc.

Comment: In other words, I do not get your sentence.  WHAT LOG SPECIFICALLY?  Because I have not found on that shows me this information on updates only.  where is this other log besides the SVN Log? Can you be a bit more clear if you're planning on helping me out?

Comment: @coffeeaddict: Perhaps you should cut back on the caffeine? You're getting pretty agitated and a little rude with people trying to help you out... I mean, three comments in three minutes, and starting to SHOUT by the third one?

Comment: Yes, and I was looking for some other logs such as for svn...what you were stating.  Anything that could show me this.  Who knows if Tortoise also kept a log, you never know.

Comment: Ken, when someone replies with a one liner that makes no sense, it's a bit annoying ok?  If you're going to reply to help someone else, make an effort to make sense or be thorough. After all, as posters such as myself we're expected to also be "thorough" so that YOU understand MY question.

Comment: I do appreciate Tom's reply.  And Ken, and whoever else, let people be human and yes, we will get a bit irritated.  Let it go.

Comment: And Ken, my 3 comments were to explain myself...big deal if there were 3 in a row. Read it for what it is. Don't jump to conclusions such as me drinking so much coffee or being so "agitated" when it's not that clear if the person sitting on the other end really is. Text doesn't convey what you assume it to be.

Comment: I know what SVN is vs. Tortoise also.  But thanks again Tom!  I still wanted to know if there were some logs I just was not aware of on EITHER end.

Comment: I dont think you typed enough comments within a ten minute period...should drink more coffee