# Is there a way that I find out what user(s) has made "svn update" from a repository?

Tags: svn, repository

I own a repository and I've created users who are able to read and write on it.
The SVN log shows what users have made "commit" but I would like to know what users have made specifically "svn update" from the repository?
I've been looking for on internet but I  haven't found the way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are running your own `subversion` server?

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin access to the server, you can find what you are looking for in the answer of this question: [How to tell if someone has downloaded the latest code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631972/how-to-tell-if-someone-has-downloaded-the-latest-code)

Another solution could be the use of [client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks), if you are using TortoiseSVN client.